# add transparent layer on youtube player & disable right click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
.wrapper-noaction {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -558px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.video-stat {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.player-control {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 7.5%;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.control {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-stat">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <div id="ytplayer" class="embed-responsive-item"></div>
            <div class="wrapper-noaction"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="player-control text-center">
            <span class="control" (click)="play();start=!start"><i class="icon-control-play" [class.icon-control-play]="start" [class.icon-control-pause]="!start" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <span class="control" (click)="stop();start=true"><i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <span class="control" (click)="volume()"><i class="icon-volume-2" [class.icon-volume-2]="!ismuted" [class.icon-volume-off]="ismuted" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

hello i am using angular 2 ytplayer to embed youtube videos in my project. i want to prevent user to click or right click on video player. i have added one transparent layer on video player so user won't be able to click or right click on player & it is working fine for medium screen sizes. but, not works for different screen sizes. how can i make it responsive with player. so user wont be able to right click on player on any screen size.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid user Clicking the video you should put it on background.
here is a little example:

```
<div id="bgndVideo" class="player" 
     data-property="{videoURL:'http://youtu.be/BsekcY04xvQ',containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:0, opacity:1}">
</div>
```

you can find it [here](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/wiki)

If it's not working you can create a directive that will catch the click and re-interprete it.
This should work, except if you go full screen

With best regards,